# Is a 'timeout' of 0.2 ms for UART communication realistic?

Tags: uart, communication, speed, timeout, overhead

In most examples (from Arduino/STM32/whatever) I see timeouts of 10 to 100 ms for different kind of communication.

However, I am wondering how much 'overhead' there is. Assuming I want to send 8 bytes (including stop bits + overhead, via RS485, 2.5 mbps), and getting a response back (let's say also 8 bytes). This would take: 64 bits / 2500000 bits/s = 32 us.

Now there needs to be some processing (interrupt handling) from both sides (sending + receiving). I'm using HAL which has some more overhead maybe, so let's take a huge 10,000 instructions. On a 72 MHz CPU this would take 10,000/72,000,000 = 138 us.

This totals less than 200 us together... 
Do I miss something?

(note that I intend to use interrupts, and probably later DMA since it will even have less overhead high likely).

**EDIT**

- Communication from an STM32F103C8T6 to another STM32F103C8T6
- Both running at 72 MHz
- RS-485 via UART, 2.5 mbps
- There are no other higher priority interrupts (that can block UART)
- Requirement: not hard, but preferably multiple messages within 1 ms.

Comment: Who are you communicating with, what are the specifications? There should be ICS (inter char spacing) specifications to which you have to abide. If you're communicating with yourself, you can specify your own to be less than 0,2ms and then you good to go..

Comment: I guess those examples really don't care about timing and are randomly thrown.  But there are some devices/IC that takes their time to process the data that you sent , so you need to see what processing time the other IC is taking in consideration when communicating.

Comment: @MaNyYaCk I do my own processing, I want to put it in interrupts, and should not do much more than copying the received 8 bytes into another buffer to be processed later in the main loop. With processing I mean actually the overhead time for the HAL interrupt handlers to be called/executed.

Comment: @Andrés The ICS I would think is part of the overhead (of 8 bytes), or is the ICS for UART/RS485 much higher?

Comment: You need to consider the other interrupts that might occur. Are there higher priority interrupts that can block the UART? You haven't told us anything about that.

Comment: Not that it adds much, but serial comms is usually 10 bits per byte on the wire. (N,8,1 setup). The HAL is a bit opaque for a lot of stuff, and some examples I have seen take quite a while to actually get to the interrupt handler although they were edge cases.

Comment: Why would you want to use a UART timeout feature? Not all comms systems do? Have you a specific reason?

Comment: @PeterSmith I'm wondering about this 'quite a while' ... and probably I can pack most messages in 5 bytes, so 3 bytes are for the N/1 bits). Is that 'quite' a while 1 us, 1 ms?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson There are no others (as far as I can see), or if there are, it will be very fast.

Comment: @Andyaka Because if I sent something, and I don't get an error callback neither a normal UART message back, the sender will never know if the message has been sent, or can I assume for UART I always get either a transmit error or transmit completion callback?

Comment: Sorry, but your understanding of the other system interrupts seems pretty thin...that would be a good reason to allow a long timeout.

Comment: @andyaka sorry it's not only that, it's also assuming to get a response back from the receiver of the message, to pass the 'token' (for RS485) to another.

Comment: If it's a master/slave system then the master not getting a response from a slave (when interrogated) means either the slave detected an error or the slave response was in error. Either scenario means an unreliable communique was received and the master should retry. I don't know if this is what you are thinking of but it doesn't require a UART timeout feature - it's dealt with in the protocol. Protocols must consider these scenarios (and others). What if this, what if that etc..

Comment: You only get a "transmit complete" callback if you write an interrupt handler for such an event. What sort of "transmit errors" would you expect to occur, other than a transmit buffer overflow?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson You are right ... I will think better about the other interrupts I can expect. Thanks for this notification.

Comment: @Andyaka ... You mean instead of to try it to do within UART, I should after sending a UART message, starting a timer, and when the timer elapses, check if I got a response... Actually this is indeed what I need.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson e.g. when the slave cannot be reached, or is powered down for some reason. However, I now know I should probably use a separate timer (independing of UART).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is, unfortunately, "it depends".

What are you talking to? What kind of processing do the nodes have to do before they can respond? How long does it actually take for the signal to travel along the cable and be received (this only really matters for REALLY long RS485 links)? What are the limits (driver enable and turnaround) on your RS485 drivers?

Timeouts are always a good idea -- they ensure that no matter what happens on the wire, your device will respond in a predictable and controlled manner. It means your protocol will be more robust and a comm glitch won't kill the link. However, 200us seems *really* tight and I have to ask why you would want to enforce such a fast timeout? 2.5mpbs is pretty fast, but you are talking about RS485 and need to manage the DE and inter-frame timing as well: have you given these items any thought because they have a *direct* impact on the link capabilities and ultimately your timeout value.

If you're using UARTs with hardware driver enable assist this is a bonus, especially at such high data rates; otherwise you're going to be either spinning waiting for the transmit shift register to be empty (NOT the holding register!) or incurring extra interrupt processing to turn the driver off when the last bit has been put on the wire. Some drivers also require an additional bit of time before being disabled which can add some more time to the equation.

What provisions does the protocol you're using have for data integrity? Do you have to calculate CRCs or enforce actual parameter integrity? These will eat up reception and packet processing time as well, especially if you don't have hardware assistance. Does the protocol allow for packet fragmentation or out of order transmission and reception? What happens in the case of a collision? You've not given nearly enough information and I suspect from the style of your question that you've not given these important things the thought they require for us to be able to answer your question properly.

Take some time and think through the problem. 2.5mbps on a system with a 72MHz clock doesn't have a lot of time to spend on these things, particularly if you're doing other data processing in addition to running the comm link. The processing power involved isn't a lot, but you seem to be intentionally tying one hand behind your own back and giving yourself a much more difficult problem without a good reason.

And finally -- if at the end of the day you want to wing it... why not just pick a number for timeout and experiment? Load the systems down, give yourself the longest physical link, make it kind of shitty, add some noise and uncertainty, elevate the temperature and see where the system starts to break. In reality you'd be ideally doing this anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer (I used my votes so I will upvote tomorrow). You gave me a lot of things to think about. Some where I know the answer from (like I have very short cable, actually I'm planning to connect them connector to connector, so only internal AWG wire), I would have to check the limits for the RS485 drivers. I want a 200 us timeout because I want to do like 5 of such messages (between different devices) within 1 ms. I'm using STM32F1's UARTs, so I assume these have hardware acceleration.

Comment: I am using HAL so I guess it will take care of the inter-frame, the DE I can set (GPIO pin toggle). I am assume I can use the UART interrupts generated by HAL. Data processing is light, but indeed, CRC checks I had in mind, and possibly retries in case of a comm/CRC problem. However, maybe even more important is just try. Maybe I want to think ahead too much. Or solving problems which are not existing yet.

Comment: HAL has nothing to do with the inter-frame timing comes; this comes from the protocol you implement. Basically "when am I allowed to send data". I do believe that the HAL enables hardware driver control for UARTs which support it.

Comment: I don't need inter-frame timing, as soon as as a messge is received, a response can be sent (within the timeout I specify). There is always only one device talking (to keep it simple).

Comment: Actually you *do* need interframe timing; this is probably the critical spec for this whole design. Basically once you signal to turn off your transmitter the driver needs to "release" the bus to let other devices talk. If you don't do this and just jam your messages one after the other then you can end up with the first bit of the message missing. If the network is long or variable-length this will also have an impact. When you're switching direction on the bus this minimum delay is also called turnaround time.

Comment: Thanks for the description. And yes, I'm indeed intending to use it. The idea is that only one device sends a message at a time (using some kind of token), when the device is ready sending (should not take long), it passes the token to the next one (sort of). So the interframe timing happens automatically because the only who can send should have the token, for that I intend to make 'command' messages and responses, when the sender sends a command, the receiver processes it, sends a response and by that the token is back to the receiver, who can send it to another device.

Comment: (see also previous comment)... if you mean I should not sent two consecutive items without any 'gap' ... I assume HAL will receive all bytes (if I put an interrupt to the UART handler)... Since every command has a specified length (sent with the command) and responses have always a fixed length, I don't need a gap (hopefully no device will miss a byte). Than there might be a problem.

Comment: If you are relying on the receiving device to process the packet before sending a response (and there are no other devices which might "sneak in") then I think this is acceptable. Interframe time comes into play when devices try to push the boundaries or you aren't using peripherals with hardware FIFOs (or with tiny FIFOs and large packets).

Comment: Yes the receiver only needs to 'copy' the packet, check CRC, if OK sent back an ACK, otherwise a NACK. I may need interframes but not for now. But this can be as easy as occasionally use a 'long' delay. Just to make sure that all devices know a new 'series' of packages start.

Answer (score 3):

> This totals less than 200 us together... Do I miss something?

In case the other party is a PC: USB timing. This is usually scheduled in full USB frames (for full speed), and can add up to about 1.5ms of latency. Even more latency is possible when the PC is "loaded".

In case the other party is another µC, your 200µs seem to be a usable timeout.

Comment: It's not a PC, but good to know USB has some latency too. (I used my votes today so I will upvote tomorrow).